# How to set <security-domain> dynamicly in jboss-web.xml during ant task execution

Tags: java, ant, jboss, jboss-web

Based on ant task, I have to define security domain value in jboss-web.xml file.

For example, if ant task is "test" the security-domain value should be 
security-domain-test

if ant task is "live" the security-domain value should be 
security-domain-live

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You may want to use a "replace" ant task :  https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html